# How can I tell if the order of events matters in a probability question?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

When I studied combinatorics, it seemed pretty clear where order mattered and where it didn't. Probability questions don't give as many hints as to whether order matters and I'm looking for some advice on properly interpreting questions. Here's an example below that I answered incorrectly:

> Two fair dice are rolled. Let $X$ be the absolute value of the difference between
> the two numbers on the dice. Calculate the probability that $X < 3$.

And here is my approach:

Since it seems like we're rolling both dice at once here, the roll is one event. The sample space should be $6 \choose 2$$+ 6$ because we should have $6 \choose 2$ unordered pairs of all possible rolls, plus the six cases where the number on each die is equal to the other on a particular roll. Then I calculated by hand all the cases where $X < 3$ ($X = 0$ was $6$, $X = 1$ was $5$ and $X = 2$ was $4$), added them up, and divided by the sample space calculated above.

But this solution is wrong. Order does matter and the sample space is $6^2$. For every combination I calculated, there are two ways to order them, so  I had to multiply the frequencies of my events by two (except for the event that the two dice rolled the same number). Where is my thinking going wrong?

Comment: This is hard to follow. Did you mean to write $\binom 62 + 6$?  In any case, your method is flawed because your outcomes are not equally probable.  An unmatched pair is twice as probable as a double.

Comment: To stress, the beauty of working with ordered pairs is that they are all equally probable.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I meant $6 \choose 2$$+ 6$. What is an unmatched pair? What you said seems like it would be a really helpful and clear criterion to help me decide on these kinds of problems. Just want to understand exactly what you're saying.

Comment: @311411 You're saying to give them an order, but why? What tips you off that order matters in this problem?

Comment: Every double has probability $\frac 1{36}$. Each unmatched unordered pair has probability $\frac 1{18}$. You can use that to solve the problem using your sample space if you want.

Comment: To stress: there is nothing wrong with working with ordered pairs nor is there anything wrong with working with unordered pairs. You just have to get the probabilities right.

Comment: It is given in words, but remember there is a calculation described in the problem statement: $|X_{red}-X_{blue}|$. We are interested in possible values of $|X_{red}-X_{blue}|$. But if I tell you I did the experiment and $|X_{red}-X_{blue}|$ was observed to be $=1$, part of your job is to go "under the hood" of your machine and see how that could happen. The blue die, the red die, subtraction and absolute value are the components of your experimental machine.

Comment: @lulu Okay, I think I see what you're saying. I think I'm confused by your answer because it seems to me that you'd have to have already recognized that order matters to calculate the different probabilities of doubles / unmatched pairs, right? I think what I'm confused about is recognizing that order matters

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. I'm only using the order as a computational tool.  Do it with unordered pairs of you want, just get the probabilities right.

Comment: Think about coin tosses.  The probability you get two heads is one fourth. Same for two tails. Getting one of each had probability one half.  Not equal. And I never mentioned order.

Comment: @lulu The coin toss example makes sense. But I'm having some trouble connecting that to the problem I have. Any chance you have any good reading materials for an in-depth explanation. I'm so bad when it comes to probability, so I really appreciate the patience.

Comment: I will delete my attempt to explain using space versus time - that is not helpful. It occurs to me the problem and answer are *unaltered* if expressed this way: *The red die is rolled first, and observed. Secondly, we roll the blue die and observe it as well. We calculate $|X_{red}-X_{blue}|$; what is the probability this is $<3\,$?* The independence discussed in user's answer is the important thing.

Comment: The art of problem solving book on probability and combinatorics is pretty strong,

Comment: @311411 Thanks for the responses. I'm having trouble connecting what you wrote to my problem, but I always appreciate someone trying to help. What I got from this discussion is this: if we have more than one event, ordered tuples of those events are all equally likely. Is this right?

Comment: @lulu just purchased. thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: To the OP (i.e. original poster): My mistake for not reading your question closely enough. Mike Earnest left me a comment, which caused me to re-think my answer. I agree that my answer totally missed the point of the question that you were asking. Also, Graham Kemp's answer is directly on point. So, I have deleted my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When determining probability *by counting* atoms of the event, you want to be counting *equally probable* atoms.

So order matters because *all ordered pairs are equally probable*.

Unordered pairs are not equally probable.   Each of the $\binom 62$ pairs of distinct faces are twice as probable as each of the $6$ pairs of same faces.

$$2\times \binom 62+6=2\times\dfrac{6\times 5}{2\times 1}+6\\~=6^2$$

Comment: Someone else also mentioned something similar to this. It seems like this is the right answer, but I'm having trouble grasping why all ordered pairs are equally probable. What does that mean? How did you know that the pairs of distinct faces are more probable than the 6 matched faces?

Comment: All ordered pairs have equal probability because each face of the individual dice has an equally probability to land face up.  Thus these 36 outcomes form a partition of unbiased events.  @AndrewLubrino